# Generalization With Inherited Classes

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, uml, grasp

There are 2 different design. Second one is(below) improved version of first one. Difference is that I add 2 child class to B. So A is dependended to 2 child class now. but what will happen if B has more child classes later?

Is it really best practice? Especially with GRASP perspective?

[image: two different version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instad of having an association to each classes, I would prefer the following.

[image]

Comment: But doesnt this mean A will have an instance of B? This is like "B b= new B" in A class and in this case I can not use sub1 and sub2.

Comment: yes that's mean that A will have at least one B instance but sub1 and sub2 instances are also B instances. So the code B b = new sub2(); is valid also. You can also set B as abstract in order to model the fact that you will never have B instances